# why are struct/union childs of global not allowed as template reference parameter - but the globals itself?

Tags: c++, templates, global

I try to reference to an child element of an global variable by using an template parameter - it does work for globals but not for childs of globals - why is the position resolving of an child not possible at compile-time?

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
typedef unsigned short word_t;

struct byte_reg_t
{
     byte_t low;
     byte_t high;
};

union word_reg_t
{
     word_t value;
     byte_reg_t part;
};

word_t rax;
byte_t rah;
word_reg_t r16;
byte_reg_t r8;

template<typename ValueType, ValueType& Ref>
ValueType ret_ref()
{
     return Ref;
}

int main()
{
    word_t x = ret_ref<word_t,rax>();
    byte_t h = ret_ref<byte_t,rah>();
    //word_t sx = ret_ref<word_t,r16.value>(); // compile error
    //byte_t sh = ret_ref<byte_t,r16.part.low>(); // compile error
    //byte_t sh2 = ret_ref<byte_t,r8.low>(); // compile error

    return 0;
}
```

the VS2010 and clang 3.1 compiler does not allow the // compile error lines

thx for any clear description because i don't see any technical reason for that behavior of the compilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in the C++ Standard. Sorry for being outdated, but my version (ISO/IEC 14882, 2nd Ed. 2003) says (page 246):

> §14.3.2 Template non-type arguments
>
> ```
>    [..]
> ```
>
> 3 [Note: Addresses of array elements and names or 
>            addresses of non-static class members are not acceptable template-arguments.[..]]

Comment: this is not an answer to the question. disallowed C++ behavior by definition can be found disallowed in the C++ standard.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb If the question is "why does the compiler not allow this?", then "because the standard says it's invalid" is a correct answer, as opposed to "because the compiler has a bug". If the question is "why does the standard not allow this?", then this answer is useless. I'm not sure what's asked in this question.

Comment: Well for us who didn't take part in the discussions and the creation of the formulations of the standard document, the answer "Because the standard forbids it" is indeed the correct one to the question "Why is xyz not allowed?". The reasoning behind the formulations in the standard is another question and can effectively only be answered by the standards commission. Actually, I have never heard of a standard addendum that explains all the reasoning behind what was standardized.

Comment: no that is not the answer to such a question. if i ask you "why is murder disallowed?" and you answer "because the law disallows it" you dont need to be a lawyer for that answer to be wrong. an answer being right or wrong/inappropriate doesn't have anything to do with who states it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Actually, that is not so easy. What about death penalty? Isn't that murder, too? So the law allows murder for states, and disallows it (mostly) for their inhabitants. What is right, what is wrong? But we're going off topic here. Fortunately, technical discussions are usually easier.

Comment: beside beeing so defined - is there any technical reason that a global child-member can't be resolved as template parameter?

Comment: Vandevoorde and Josuttis mention in their book that class member names are not considered to be variables. However, I have no standard reference for this.